# Why my bluetooth don't have mac address?

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth device CSR 4.0 installed in Ubuntu 20.04 but it appears shutdown and no mac address.

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
    TX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 commands:1 errors:1
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: oops guess I am blind

Comment: do you have btmgmt installed? and if so what does that show? https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/btmgmt.1.html

Answer (score 0):

BT devices don't have MAC addresses. They use a 48-bit static address which is randomly generated. Why do you need a MAC adress?

Comment: he made a mistake and probably wants to know why it says `BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0`